# Option to download at 64 Bit on unity?

Tags: unity, 64-bit, downloads

How do I set the ubuntu unity 14.04 to download at 64bit. I currently use Windows7.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply download it from the web page, I linked it here for you:

> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04&architecture=amd64

For downloading the server version simply switch out the word `desktop` with `server`.

And another link which will work as well is this one:

> http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/

<sub>**Note: To editors, the clear writing of the links is intentional and part of the answer.**</sub>

Comment: I personally prefer http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/

Comment: Ends up at the same place in the end I guess but I'll add that link.

Comment: Thanks. I did this & it downloaded to 32bit. Why would it do that? My laptop is 64bit.

Comment: @Willie how the `.iso` file is named ?

Comment: @Willie click [here for Desktop version 64 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) ,  and [here is server version (64 bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso)

Comment: "Note: To editors, the clear writing of the links is intentional and part of the answer." but they look so bad! I won't edit you again though if you don't want me too.

Comment: @Willie If there is `amd64` in the filename, then it is a 64-bit download for Intel and AMD.

Comment: @MarkKirby Wanted to make clear that i link to an official place, this way people can simply copy and paste the text if they don't trust the link itself. Normaly I appreciate the edits and it is not a roll back as you can see. :)

Comment: @Videonauth Sure I get that, it is your post you can format however you like, I think though perhaps, even with the disclaimer, it might still get edited again, people love to get that 2 rep :)

Comment: @MarkKirby yep might be, but mind the sentence behind my first link, it would not make sense without it being clear. Just don't want you to feel offended :)

Comment: @Videonauth I don't. I have been doing this for a while, you would not believe how many times edits get undone round here.